# How to set custom gravity attribute to custome view in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, kotlin, android-custom-view

Let say I have a custom view and it has an attribute named myGravity which only has 3 value myStartVertical|myCenter|myEndVertical

How can I pull this off?

My layout should be like this

```
  <com.myapp.customview.MyCustomView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/auth_button_height"
    android:text="I'm a custom view"
    app:myGravity="myCenter"
    />
```

My attrs.xml should be like this

```
    <declare-styleable name="MyCustomView">
        <attr name="myGravity">
            <flag name="myStartVertical" value="0x97" />
            <flag name="myCenter" value="0x96" />
            <flag name="myEndVertical" value="0x95" />
        </attr>
    </declare-styleable>
```

And MyCustomView.kt should be like this

```
class MyCustomView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0) 
    : ConstraintLayout(context, attributeSet, defStyleAttr) {
  init{
    LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.view_app_button, this)
    attributeSet?.run {
            val props = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attributeSet, R.styleable.AppButton)
            try {
                for (i in 0..props.indexCount) {
                    when (val attr = props.getIndex(i)) {
                        R.styleable.AppButton_android_text -> {
                            text = props.getString(attr) ?: ""
                        }
                        R.styleable.AppButton_textGravity -> {
                            // TODO: get the gravity value here
                            myGravity = .....
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            } finally {
                props.recycle()
            }
  }
}
```

What should I fill in TODO?

Comment: Are you asking what type that will be? If so, it's an `Int`, so `myGravity = props.getInt(attr, -1)`.

Comment: Yes, Thanks @MikeM. That's is what am I looking for.

Answer (score 0):

With your question, we have two cases

**Case 1**:
You apply the `gravity` to the `MyCustomView` with it's parent view

EX: You put the `MyCustomView` as a child of the `LinearLayout`

```
val layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
layoutParams.gravity = /* your gravity -> set gravity of your custom view with it's parent */
// myCustomView.layoutParams = layoutParams
```

**Case 2**:
You apply the `gravity` to make all the child of the `MyCustomView` view are on the `top`, `left`,...

EX: Let the `MyCustomView` extends from the `LinearLayout`

```
val view = MyCustomView(this)
view.gravity = /* your gravity -> set gravity to all the child of the LinearLayout */
```

Comment: Actually, @Mike M got the idea. I'll mark his comment as an accepted answer if I can. Thanks anyway.